# Magento Data Base error

Tags: attributes, database, filter, filterable-attributes

i am new to magento and have no developer skills but i can do bit of copy pasting etc very well.

i have recently migrated the server and now i am facing some issue with our database.
please follow this link for error

http://www.smartteck.co.uk/storage/solid-state-drives-ssd.html?feature_394=N

when ever on our site you use any filter it give this error. i have contacted STIC but they have the worst customer support ever.

can any one read the error and tel me how to sort this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to Disable the module "Sell Ingram Micro, tech & 100 ..." Your big error file mentions a few times that this module's files struggle with something :).
If you look at the module's website you will see they require php5 and proper file permission. If your site was working fine on the other server I would think that file permission is the cause for this error.

[module documentation](http://support.stockinthechannel.com/troubleshooting-the-plug-in/)

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes i am using that application, but as you can see the error does not suggest any where that there is a permission error or some thing, but i will still run that command and will let you know the results.

Comment: I have tried to run this command: find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;  but it seems the error is still there, any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when procedures are not imported in the database during migration. Please follow the steps below and see if that sorts out the issue:

1. `mysqldump -u <Your User Name> -p --routines --no-create-info --no-create-db --no-data --skip-opt <Your Database Name> > procedures.sql`
   Run this on the server which has original database
2. Login to MySQL on your second server using terminal and import the file that was exported in the step above.

**NOTE:** You might get errors saying "Procedure  already exist". In that case you will have to drop the procedure first by using syntax provided in [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-procedure.html) and then reimport again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this and will report back if it works or not.

Comment: cheers! @shafiq